# Display the error message based on the custom Error Code throwing Exception in c#

Tags: c#

I want to catch the exception and based on the exception occurred define the custom error code and display the Error message

I would like to build a xml file to distinguish exceptions in my program and later do exception translations.

For example:

```
<EXCEPTIONS>
     <EXCEPTION tip="MyException">
          <ERROR ID="1">
             <DESCRIPTION>The server is not operational</DESCRIPTION>
         </ERROR>
     </EXCEPTION >
</EXCEPTIONS>
```

Comment: Consider creating a custom exception type for your application. Add the error codes etc to the exception.data. In your final exception handler, look up the error codes and map against your xml and do the needful for display.

Comment: can you show me an example.  I have created my own exception and now how to map all the error codes to display?

Comment: What type of an application is this ? asp.net? win forms? wpf? How do you have your central exception handler configured?

Comment: Our application in asp.net and i will validate the text box and if it fails all the error messages are added and these error messages are throwing through the exception class. now i want it from the xml error codes defined as explained above.